# How to evaluate dynamical conditioning/pseudo code

Tags: logic

I am having a hard time even to formulate my question, so here it is:

I have an application that the user can go in and define on a webpage the logic one wants to evaluate for the student to comply with:

> Student must take classes (MATH111 OR (MATH101 AND MATH103))

I have an array of all its enrolled classes like:

> [MATH101,MATH102,MATH123,MATH444]

How do I evaluate my array on that expression to check if the students satisfies the AND/OR clause?

Comment: "I have an array of all its classes like" What does "its" refer to? The classes each student has already passed? What is your goal? To decide if a specific student satisfies the condition or to return all the students that satisfy the condition?

Comment: The array I have is the classes the student has (I will edit the question). The goal is to decide if the student satisfies the criteria defined on the AND/OR clause

Comment: One option may be compiling the expression to a [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram).

Comment: Are you asking how to **parse** an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your terminology is unusual. I wouldn't speak about "evaluating an array on an expression", but rather about "evaluating an expression using a variable assignment". Your array is, essentially, a variable assignment stating which boolean variables are true and which are false.

You can represent the expression as a syntax tree, having `AND`/`OR` internal nodes, and variable names `MATH101` as leaves.

Then, you can evaluate the expression simply visiting the tree. In pseudocode:

```
boolean function eval(tree, array):

    if tree is a leaf X:
       return the boolean answering (X in array?)
    else if tree is OR(t1,t2):
       b1 = eval(t1, array)     # recursive calls
       b2 = eval(t2, array)
       return (b1 || b2)
    else tree must be AND(t1,t2):
       b1 = eval(t1, array)     # recursive calls
       b2 = eval(t2, array)
       return (b1 && b2)
```

If you want, you can even implement short-circuit evaluation to save some time. If your expressions are short it won't make any difference w.r.t. performance, though.

Comment: with this approach I would have a tree representing my logical expression. But its not clear where I would input my array of classes the student has

Comment: @Walucas I added an explicit `array` argument. In principle, you could avoid that argument and store it in a global variable (or an outer local variable, if your programming language support those)

Comment: Sorry, now you lost me. I cant see how the array get used on the comparison results

Comment: @Walucas I use it in the line `return the boolean answering (X in array?)`, which scans the array and returns true if X is found, false otherwise. A linear search suffices.

Comment: ok, think I got it, let me implement in python and see if that works!

Comment: it worked for a one level tree, but shouldnt be hard to make it deeper, tks